# How to set data on option select element from mysql database to update with php + jquery + ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I need some help because I'm not to advanced programming with php. I'm sorry about my English, so I will try to explain my problem to try to solve it. I do not know how to set correctly data on  of  html element from database when I want to update any data of any registration on a table. Explaining with details when I want update/edit any registration through on any table (database table) if in the form as a select field I do not know how to set there a data that belongs to some registration on the table of database to change with another available options. I try in different ways but did not work perfectly.
I will place down here code of the exercise project.

HTML form to update

```
<select class="form-control" id="txtUserRoleEdicao" name="txtUserRoleEdicao">
                                <option value="" selected id="fakeOption">Escolha o tipo de usuário em relação ao previlégios</option>
                                <?php
                                $sqlPesquisarEdicaoROLE_USERS = "SELECT idROLE_USER, tipoROLE_USER from ROLE_USERS";
                                $resultPesquisarEdicaoROLE_USERS = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlPesquisarEdicaoROLE_USERS);
                                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_row($resultPesquisarEdicaoROLE_USERS)) : ?>

                                    <option id="optionROLE_USER" value="<?php echo $dados[0]; ?>"> <?php echo $dados[1]; ?> </option>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </select>
```

Code js that recovery data from php to set data in the form:

```
function recuperarDadosUsuario(idUsuario) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "idUsuario=" + idUsuario,
                url: "../procedimentos/usuarios/recuperarDadosEdicaoUsuario.php",
                success: function(r) {
                    dados = jQuery.parseJSON(r);

                    $('#txtIdUsuario').val(dados['idUsuario']);
                    $('#txtNomeFuncionarioUsuarioEdicao').val(dados['nomeFuncionario']);
                    $('#optionROLE_USER').val(dados['idRoleUsers']);
                    $('#optionROLE_USER').text(dados['tipoRole']);
                    $('#fakeOption').prop('selected', false);
                    $('#optionROLE_USER').prop('selected', true);
                    $('#txtEmailEdicao').val(dados['emailUsuario']);
                    $('#txtSenhaEdicao').val(dados['senhaUsuario']);

                }
               
            });
            $('#optionROLE_USER').prop('selected', false);
            $('#fakeOption').prop('selected', true);
        }
```

Code of recuperarDadosEdicaoUsuario.php file

```
<?php
require_once "../../classes/conexao.php";
require_once "../../classes/usuarios.php";

$idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario'];

$con = new Conexao();
$conexao = $con->conectar();

$obj = new Usuarios();

echo json_encode($obj->recuperarDadosEdicaoUsuario($idUsuario));
```

PHP function that recovery data from database

```
public function recuperarDadosEdicaoUsuario($idUsuario)
    {
        $con = new Conexao();
        $conexao = $con->conectar();

        $sql = "SELECT u.idUsuario, f.nomeFuncionario, u.email, u.senha, r.idROLE_USER, r.tipoROLE_USER from usuarios as u inner join ROLE_USERS as r on u.idRole_Users = r.idROLE_USER INNER JOIN funcionarios as f on u.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario where u.idUsuario = '$idUsuario'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

        $resultItem = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        $dados = array(
            "idUsuario" => $resultItem[0],
            "nomeFuncionario" => $resultItem[1],
            "emailUsuario" => $resultItem[2],
            "senhaUsuario" => $resultItem[3],
            "idRoleUsers" => $resultItem[4],
            "tipoRole" => $resultItem[5]
        );
        return $dados;
    }
```

Comment: HI, does `dados` has correct values or not ?

Comment: Swati, dados has the correct values

Comment: can you show output of that ? Also are ids correct which you are using to assign values?

Comment: Yes I can. Also, the data with their IDs that has to be selected I can restore, but it is not pre-selected and in the last way that I try did not work perfectly. Because after updating the data, it repeated itself in the select options.

Comment: can you show html as well ?

Comment: yes, I can show